# Gendered my _id with firstname and lastname

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey i will generated my _id with firstname and lastname in mongodb but i have problem with this,i will generated id like this : '_id':'midoxnavas' will midox firstname and navas last name

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

module.exports = function (mongoose) {
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // noinspection JSAnnotator
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        _id='firstName'+'lastName',
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        userName: {type: String, unique: true},
        email: {type: String, unique: true},
        password: String,
        salt: String,
        role : {type: String, enum : ['User','Manager','Admin']},
    });

    // generating a hash
    UserSchema.methods.generateHash = function (password) {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    };

    // checking if password is valid
    UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    };

    UserSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
}
```

the erreur is

```
 _id='firstName'+'lastName',
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

Have you any solution ?

Comment: No, no, no! The _id must be a mongodb id. You might wanna use a composed index instead. And what do you think `=` will do in an object literal??

Answer (score 0):

`_id` - generate automaticly.

I think you need create `virtual` field [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)

```
PersonSchema
    .virtual('name.full')
    .get(function () {
        return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
    });
```